# Exact output was coming but some error was raising

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the above Python code the exact output was coming but after output they were showing some error

```
    def main():
    i=1
    while i < 3:
     
     inputString = input()
     inputStringTwo = input()
     inputStringThree = input()
     outputString=inputString[0] + inputStringTwo[0] + inputStringThree[0]
     print(outputString)
     i+=1

main()
```

Here we are giving input as

```
Very
Important
Person
```

The Error was

```
VIP

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 5, in main
    inputString = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Here **VIP** is the output

For Question and test cases please refer below link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cXmIW56uurB83V4FNRuNw9VhJ7RcYU9j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: its running fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using an online IDE;

EOFError is raised when one of the built-in functions input() or raw_input() hits an end-of-file condition (EOF) without reading any data. **This error is sometimes experienced while using online IDEs**. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-eoferror-exception-in-python/)

try not to use online IDEs its better to download [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: Ok but i want to do only in online ide. I have no another chance. I cannot use Python. It is prohibited to use python

Comment: oh ok well this online ide is pretty reliable https://www.online-python.com/